# Spring Cloud: Hystrix shows no data on ping

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, hystrix, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm using hystrix in my spring boot application but when i access the */hystrix-stream* page there is no data. It shows only "ping: ". 
In my *pom.xml* i've got the following:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-ribbon</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have enabled Hystrix and HystrixDashboard. Additionally i'm using ribbon in my application. The HystrixCommand looks like this:

```
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "defaultFallback")
public byte[] doGet() {
    return this.restTemplate.getForObject("http://myInstance/api/v3/ressource",byte[].class);
}

public byte[] defaultFallback() {
    System.out.println("Now doing fallback!");
    return null;
}
```

When i shut down *myInstance* there is no fallback called, ribbon shows me only this failure:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
I/O error on POST request for "http:/myInstance/api/v3/ressource": Connection
refused; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Comment: From where are you calling doGet method? From the same class or from some external one?

Comment: Do you have the entire stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Your spring boot application must enable the circuit breaker.

Like the next example:

```
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableWebMvc
public class ClientManagerApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ClientManagerApp.class, args);
    }
}
```